# What type of DOM element is the host element in Angular

Tags: angular

```js
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
}
```

By default `ElementRef` is `ElementRef<any>`, so `this.el.nativeElement` has type `any`.

**But what is the really appropriate type for the host element?**

For example, I would like to use `this.el.nativeElement.width` with typing, and not by using `any`. If I set `ElementRef<HTMLElement>`, I can't get `width` attribute because not all `HTMLElement` have the `width` property. However the host element really has the `width` property.

Comment: Can you do `typeof el`?

Comment: `typeof this.el` returns `'object'`